# How can I know if String.Replace or StringBuilder.Replace will modify the string?

Tags: c#, string

I want to know if I need to do `String.Replace`/`StringBuilder.Replace` on my string.

So I have two ways to do that.

The first way:

```
var myString = new StringBuilder("abcd");
var copyMyString = myString;

myString = myString.Replace("a", "b");
if (!myString.Equals(copyMyString))//If the string Is changed
{
    //My Code
}
```

And the second:

```
var pos = myString.ToString().IndexOf("a");
if (pos > 0)
{
    myString = myString.Replace("a", "b");
    //After this line the string is replaced.
    //My Code
 }
```

What is a faster way to do this (performance)?

Is there another way to do that?

The string length sometimes can be 1MB and more.

Comment: The first one might take some time as you program will go through your string to modify the letter and then will go through both strings to compare them.
The second is faster but the problem is that it doesn't do the job. do your code if your initial string contains a certain character and you do not verify if the replacment worked before doing your code

Comment: Obviously the second is more shorter and cleaner.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The first will never be `false` because both variables refer to the same `StringBuilder`

Comment: @E-Bat shorter and cleaner code does not always mean faster or better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed this up a little by modifying your second method like so:

```
var pos = myString.ToString().IndexOf("a");
if (pos > 0)
{
    myString = myString.Replace("a", "b", pos, myString.Length - pos);
    //After this line the string is replaced.
    //My Code
 }
```

We now call [the overload of `StringBuilder.Replace()` which specifies a starting index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1bxd041(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now it doesn't need to search the first part of the string again. This is unlikely to save much time though - but it will save a little.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how often `pos > 0` (note that should probably be `pos >= 0`) is true. [`.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx) will cycle through each character until it finds what you are looking for so it's `O(n)`, this is a pretty cheap operation since it's only a single search.

The high cost here is [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx). For strings modifying them often under can be overwriting the string, the larger the string the more costly that becomes. This also can have several replaces since it finds all occurrences.

So unless `pos >= 0` is almost always `true` the second case will be more efficient but you should drop `.ToString()` as it's doing nothing.